# How to change the locale through URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, localization

In my bi-lingual Rails 4 application I have a `LocalesController` like this:

```
class LocalesController < ApplicationController

  def change_locale
    if params[:set_locale]
      session[:locale] = params[:set_locale] 
      url_hash = Rails.application.routes.recognize_path URI(request.referer).path
      url_hash[:locale] = params[:set_locale]
      redirect_to url_hash
    end
  end

end
```

A User can change his locale through this form:

```
def locale_switcher
  form_tag url_for(:controller => 'locales', :action => 'change_locale'), :method => 'get', :id => 'locale_switcher' do
  select_tag 'set_locale', options_for_select(LANGUAGES, I18n.locale.to_s)
end
```

This works.

However, right now there's no way for the user to change the language via the URL.

E.g. if a user is on the page `www.app.com/en/projects` and then manually changes the URL to `www.app.com/fr/projects`, he *should* see the French version of the page, but instead nothing happens.

This may not matter in many Rails apps but in mine it is quite important.

How can it be fixed?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You'd need to check & adjust appropriate routing rules to handle locale specific paths.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is how I did it in one of Rails 4 applications:

in *config/routes.rb*:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  scope "(:locale)", locale: /#{I18n.available_locales.join("|")}/ do
    # rest of your routes here
    # for example:
    resources :projects
  end
end
```

make sure in *config/environments/production.rb* this line is uncommented:

```
config.i18n.fallbacks = true
```

If you wish to have a `default_locale` setup other than `:en`, then in *config/application.rb*, uncomment this line:

```
config.i18n.default_locale = :de # and then :de will be used as default locale
```

Now, last part of your setup, add this method in `ApplicationController`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  before_action :set_locale

  private
    def set_locale
      I18n.locale = params[:locale] || session[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
      session[:locale] = I18n.locale
    end

   def default_url_options(options={})
     logger.debug "default_url_options is passed options: #{options.inspect}\n"
     { locale: I18n.locale }
   end
end
```

Now, your application can be accessed as: `http://localhost:3000/en/projects`, `http://localhost:3000/fr/projects`, or `http://localhost:3000/projects`. The last one `http://localhost:3000/projects` will use `:en` as its default locale(unless you make that change in application.rb).

Comment: This turns out to be working very well indeed. I think the key is to always enforce a session, no matter who or what. That way the correct locale is always kept. This is what I had missed before.

Comment: am i missing something here, when I have done the above i am getting presented with the following `http://localhost:3000/sign_in?locale=en`

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's better to set locale in `routes.rb` like this:

```
# config/routes.rb
scope "(:locale)", locale: /en|nl/ do
  resources :books
end
```

You can read more here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#setting-the-locale-from-the-url-params

**UPD.** If you also save locale to the session, you also need to update it on each request.
You can set it in the filter as suggested in the other answer. But I prefer to use less filters:

```
def locale_for_request
  locale = params[:locale]
  if locale && I18n.locale_available?(locale)
    session[:locale] = locale
  else
    session[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
  end
end

# then use it in the around filter: I18n.with_locale(locale_for_request)
```

Comment: @Tintin81 I agree with prcu, if you want the URL to define the 'true' locale, you should use the URL's locale set in routes. It doesn't really make sense to write it back to the session if it is still in the URL.

Comment: @Tintin81 If you use optional locale in the rotes, then yes, you can save locale into session. It'll help to set locale for user that came back to the url without locale. I've updated my answer for this case.

Answer (score 2):

If you want this behaviour, you are going to have to compare the URL against the session every request.
One way you might do it is like this:

```
before_filter :check_locale
def check_locale
  if session[:locale] != params[:locale] #I'm assuming this exists in your routes.rb
    params[:set_locale] = params[:locale] #Generally bad to assign things to params but it's short for the example
    change_locale
  end
end
```